# Supabase Auth Server can't find tables

Tags: postgresql, authentication, supabase

All of a sudden, I'm not able to log any users into my application (via the JS library log in methods, OAuth, Email / password). On checking the POSTGRES logs, I'm getting errors saying both:

```
relation "identites" does not exist
relation "sessions" does not exist
```

Of course, I can see these tables in my auth schema so they definitely exist. I can also see that the supabase_auth_admin role in the pg_user table has the following config:

```
["search_path=auth","idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=60000"]
```

Why can't the supabase_auth_admin find the tables? I can see from the error log that the query isn't specifying the schema explicity but since there is the useconfig set up, that shouldn't matter.

This behaviour only started after I created a new schema called "private" to hold some security definer functions and moved all my functions from the public schema to the private schema.

Snippet from the error log:

```
"query": "SELECT provider FROM identities AS identities WHERE user_id = $1",
"user_name": "supabase_auth_admin",
```

Comment: What is the output of [`SHOW search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-show.html)? Are you sure you are connecting as the `supabase_auth_admin` user? How about capitalization errors (`auth` != `Auth`)?

Comment: entering ```SHOW search_path``` in the supabase dashboard sql terminal outputs: ```"\$user", public, extensions``` however when logged into the supabase admin dashboard you are conncted as the postgres user

The connection is being made by the Supabase auth server (Gotrue) to verify user information not me so I can't really change how it connects

Comment: Can you use `psql` to connect to your database as the `supabase_auth_admin` user and run `SHOW search_path`? Can you change the password for that user and see if Supabase still connects (and runs into the errors you mentioned)? I assume Supabase is connecting as some other user (probably not as a `..._admin` user) or it is setting the `search_path` programmatically.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I isolated the issue to a trigger function on my auth schema that ran every time a user row was updated. Removing that trigger solved the issue. But I'm still not exactly sure why that error message was showing in the logs since the trigger did not reference any of those tables (sessions, identities, instances etc)

Comment: OK, I'm glad you found the problem. Feel free to write a short answer for your own question and accept it, so others with similar problems know there is a solution.